# Problem applying UDF cosine similarity to grouped ML vectors in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I'm having an error when applying an UDF (`dot_group`) to grouped data. This UDF has the aim to compute pair-wise cosine similarities among the ML `Vector` of each group made from the `features` column. The groups are made according to the `prediction` column of the input data (`cdf`). The result should be an `ArrayType`, where each item is a resultant similarity, writen to the `cosines` column. This is my attempt to do it:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from itertools import combinations
from numpy import linalg as LA


def g_dot(M):
    combs = combinations(M, 2)
    return [i.dot(j) /(LA.norm(i) * LA.norm(j)) \
                                            for i, j in combs]
dot_group = F.udf(g_dot, ArrayType(DoubleType()))


cdf = spark.createDataFrame(
            [(1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 10.0, 0.5])), 
             (0.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.0, 0.5])),
             (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 10.0, 0.1])),
             (0.0, Vectors.dense([10.0, 10.0, 0.5])),
             (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0, 0.5])),],
            ["prediction", "features"])

dfs = cdf.groupBy(["prediction"]) \
         .agg(F.collect_list("features").alias("data")) \
         .withColumn("cosines", dot_group("data"))
dfs.show()
```

... Which gives the following error. I'm not sure why this error rises, but it seems that there are problems serializing numpy operations:

```
19/02/19 16:21:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2093.0 (TID 1185)
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:155)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/02/19 16:21:39 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2093.0 (TID 1185, localhost, executor driver): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

...
19/02/19 16:21:39 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2093.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Aplication/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 336, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
  File "/Aplication/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/Aplication/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Aplication/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2000.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2093.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2093.0 (TID 1185, localhost, executor driver): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
        at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:155)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: Hi @coldspeed, I have probably millions of rows. Do you think this can be inefficient? please suggest me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Spark SQL doesn't support NumPy types. You should convert values to `float` before returning

```
@F.udf(ArrayType(DoubleType()))
def dot_group(M):
    combs = combinations(M, 2)
    return [
        # or float(i.dot(j) / (LA.norm(i) * LA.norm(j)))
        (i.dot(j) / (LA.norm(i) * LA.norm(j))).tolist()
        for i, j in combs
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you @user10465355, this solved the issue. In addition, I tested the following in order to avoid importing numpy linalg: `def g_dot(M):
...     combs = combinations(M, 2)
...     return [float(i.dot(j) /(i.norm(2) * j.norm(2)))  for i, j in combs]`